# pages/[file_id].tsx how to get the file_id in nextjs

Tags: typescript, next.js

I have a nextjs-ts code like this in my `pages/[file_id].tsx` file.

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import Script from 'next/script';
import Image from 'next/image';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

export default function ImagePage(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    console.log(req); // undefined
    return (
        <div>
        <Head>
            <title>Something</title>
            {/* How to access the file_id in the url here */}
        </Head>
        </div>
    )
}
```

How can I get the `file_id` in the url inside the code to use it?

Comment: Page components do not receive `req` or `res` parameters. They are React components, and receive props. If you want to access the dynamic route parameter you'll have to use Next.js router, e.g. `const router = useRouter(); const { file_id } = router.query;`. See https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the route parameters(file_id) through the [getServerSideProps's](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#context-parameter) context

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import Script from 'next/script';
import Image from 'next/image';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

export default function ImagePage(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse, id) {
    console.log(req); // undefined
    return (
        <div>
        <Head>
            <title>Something</title>
            {/* now you can access the file_id in the url here using id */}
        </Head>
        </div>
    )
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
      const id = context.params.id // Get file_id from slug `/pages/1`

      // Rest of `getServerSideProps` code
      return {
            props: { id: context.query.id }

}

}
```

Comment: That is the code inside a .tsx file, it does not work and can you provide a complete code?

Comment: Let me know if updated code helps you